# Concatenate objc_property_t

Tags: objective-c, properties, concatenation, exc-bad-access

I have an object named dto. This object is child of another, and his father highest class is NSObject. I would like to get all properties of dto and all its superclasses. Actually I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I want to see the propertyName in my bucle for. Thank you very much!

```
unsigned int i, superPropertyCount, propertyCount;
objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([dto class], &propertyCount);

if ([[dto class] isSubclassOfClass:[NSObject class]])
{
    memcpy(properties, properties, propertyCount * sizeof(objc_property_t));
    id superClass = [[dto class] superclass];
    while ([superClass isSubclassOfClass:[NSObject class]])
    {
        objc_property_t *superProperties = class_copyPropertyList(superClass, &superPropertyCount);

        properties = malloc((propertyCount + superPropertyCount) * sizeof(objc_property_t));

        if (properties != NULL)
        {
            memcpy(properties, properties, propertyCount * sizeof(objc_property_t));
            memcpy(properties+propertyCount, superProperties, superPropertyCount * sizeof(objc_property_t));
        }
        propertyCount = propertyCount + superPropertyCount;
        superClass = [superClass superclass];
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < propertyCount; i++)
{
    objc_property_t property = properties[i];
    NSString *propertyName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: property_getName(property)];
}
```

Comment: While it is very interesting-- useful and educational-- to plumb the depths of the runtime, this kind of introspection is generally to be avoided in production code.   It is rife with fragility.   Objective-C is not really intended to be a fully dynamic, runtime centric, language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are loosing pointer at properties at

```
properties = malloc((propertyCount + superPropertyCount) * sizeof(objc_property_t));
```

Next line of code:

```
memcpy(properties, properties, propertyCount * sizeof(objc_property_t));
```

doesn't have any effect.

BTW. don't forget to free allocated memory with `class_copyPropertyList` and `malloc`.